# Let $g\circ f = h\circ f$ for all $f$ from $A$ to $B$, prove that $g = h$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $g:B \to C$ and $h: B \to C$ be functions, so that $g
\circ f = h\circ f$ for all $f: A \to B$. To prove that $g=h$. The way I proceeded to prove is as follows:

Since $g\circ f = h\circ f$ for *all* $f$, I thought it was safe to assume that $f$ is surjective, so that $B \subset ranf$. Hence:

$(x,y) \in g \implies x \in domg \implies x \in B \implies x\in ranf \implies \exists z(z,x) \in f \implies \exists z (z,x) \in f $and $(x,y) \in g \implies \exists z(z,y) \in g\circ f \implies \exists z(z,y) \in h\circ f \implies \exists v, \exists z (z,v) \in f $and $(v,y) \in h \implies \exists z, \exists v\in f $ and $(z,x) \in f \implies v=x \implies (x,y) \in h$.

The second half of the proof is completely analogous to the first half, so I don't think it's required to write it down. However, did I prove it correctly? Was there any flaw or falt in my reasoning? I am asking for I require constant confirmation from the more professional since I am only new to set theory. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect you want to prove that $g=h$, not that $g=f$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson is there also a way to make a function arrow instead of using "implies"? As in $f: A \implies B$

Comment: `\to` to get $\to$, not `\implies`

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for noticing! I edited the post

Comment: It's even easier to take $A=B$ and left $f$ be the identity function

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but is my proof correct, though?

Comment: why do I feel like it is not true?

Comment: @FuatRay what do you mean? Where exactly am I mistaken?

Comment: Let $f$ just be a constant function taking a value in $B$. Hence $g(b) = h(b)$ for any $b \in B$.

Comment: @copper.hat but is there any "incorrectness" in my own proof?

Comment: Is $A$ fixed like $B$ and $C$, or are you letting $\forall A, \forall f:A\to B, g\circ f = h\circ f$?

Comment: @peterwhy I believe $A$ was intended to be fixed

Comment: A slightly easier way of proving this is to introduce some more notation. Also, we want to assume that $A\neq \emptyset$. For $b\in B$ denote by $f_b: A\rightarrow B$ the constant function $f_b(a)=b$ for all $a\in A$ . Pick $a_0\in A$ (here we use $A\neq \emptyset$), then we get for all $b\in B$ $$g(b)=g(f_b(a_0))=(g\circ f_b)(a_0)=(h\circ f_b)(a_0)=h(b).$$ Thus, $g=h$.

Comment: @Camelot823 It is too much work to grind through all those symbols.

Comment: Don't tag people just to ask your question again. Tag people only for clarification, if you don't understand their comment. You've already asked your question, asking it again, tagging, is nagging someone to hel0 you more, and is vaguely insulting.

Comment: If you believe that $A$ is fixed and may be fixed to be different from $B$, then [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740805/let-g-circ-f-h-circ-f-for-all-f-from-a-to-b-prove-that-g-h#comment10054290_4740805) "to take $A=B$ and left $f$ be the identity function" would not work.

Comment: If you believe that $A$ is fixed and may be fixed to have smaller cardinality than $B$, then it would not be "safe to assume that $f$ is surjective".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof cannot work, because you assume that there exists $f : A\to B$ that is surjective.
Counter-example: there is no surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Second point, there is something missing in your statement : the initial quantifier.
Indeed, the goal is to prove $$\forall x\in B\,,g(x)=h(x)$$ or, as you wrote using "formal ZF function definition", $$\forall (x,y)\in B\times C\,,(x,y)\in g\Leftrightarrow (x,y)\in h$$

You must begin with this "forall" quantifier.

However, you can process as this (supposing neither $A,B,C$ are empty) :

- $\forall x\in B$, let $f_x : A\to B$ be the constant function :
  $\forall z\in A\,,f_x (z)=x$.
- Then you'll come to $g\circ f_x(z)=h\circ f_x(z)$
- and finally    $g(x)=h(x)$,
- thus $g=h$ because at the begining there was $\forall x\in B$

Answer (score 5):

I want to pull out some things from the comments under the question.  As peterwhy noted, it's not clear if $ A $ is given ahead of time; that is, are you meant to prove
$$ \forall \, B , \; \forall \, C , \; \forall \, g \colon B \to C , \; \forall \, h \colon B \to C , \; \forall \, A , \; ( \forall \, f \colon A \to B , \; g \circ f = h \circ f ) \; \Rightarrow \; g = h $$
or
$$ \forall \, B , \; \forall \, C , \; \forall \, g \colon B \to C , \; \forall \, h \colon B \to C , \; ( \forall \, A , \; \forall \, f \colon A \to B , \; g \circ f = h \circ f ) \; \Rightarrow \; g = h \text ? $$
The difference is that (in proving the statement) you get to pick $ A $ in the second case but not in the first.

The second one is very easy to prove; your proof works, but so does the simpler one in a comment by Thomas Andrews: let $ A $ be $ B $, and let $ f $ be the identity function.  So that's probably not the intended interpretation; it's too easy.

The first one is false, for a reason first pointed out implicitly in a comment by Severin Schraven: let $ B $ be any set with at least one element, let $ C $ be any set with at least two elements, let $ g $ and $ h $ be different functions from $ B $ to $ C $ (such as the constant functions to different elements of $ C $), and let $ A $ be empty.  So that can't be it; too hard (impossible).

But many of the comments, including the one by Severin Schraven (which contains a complete answer), and also the answer by hdci, assume a modified version of the first interpretation, where we additionally assume that $ A $ is inhabited (meaning non-empty).  So that's
$$ \forall \, B , \; \forall \, C , \; \forall \, g \colon B \to C , \; \forall \, h \colon B \to C , \; \forall \, A , \; A \ne \varnothing \; \Rightarrow \; ( \forall \, f \colon A \to B , \; g \circ f = h \circ f ) \; \Rightarrow \; g = h \text . $$
This is the interpretation that's both true and not too easy; if this question came from an assignment, then you might want to check whether you were supposed to assume that $ A $ is inhabited.  (It's not necessary to assume that $ B $ and $ C $ are inhabited.)

This isn't a full answer, since other people gave the proofs for the true interpretations, but I wanted to make it clear that the nontrivial interpretation isn't quite true, and not just leave that to parentheses.